# GCP C++ SDK - Setting HTTP proxy and disabling SSL certificate verification

Tags: c++, ssl, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cpp

How can we set HTTP proxy for GCP C++ SDK?

Setting env variables using the "http_proxy" does not seem to have an effect.

Setting the SSL_CERT_FILE env variable also does not affect the SSL certificate path. CURL always seems to be using the default certificate directory.

Also, is there a way to disable SSL certificate verification in the GCP C++ SDK?

Comment: Where is your app running? Is it a local machine or any GCP product?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a duplicate of this question on GitHub:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/5584

I have answered there.